# Java Basic class use

Tags: java

Assignment:

Print `person1`'s kids, apply the `incNumKids()` method, and print again, outputting text as below. End each line with newline.

Sample output for below program:

```
Kids: 3
New baby, kids now: 4
```

Code:

```
// ===== Code from file PersonInfo.java =====
public class PersonInfo {
    private int numKids;

    public void setNumKids(int personsKids) {
        numKids = personsKids;
        return;
    }

    public void incNumKids() {
        numKids = numKids + 1;
        return;
    }

    public int getNumKids() {
        return numKids;
    }
}
// ===== end =====
```

```
// ===== Code from file CallPersonInfo.java =====
public class CallPersonInfo {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        PersonInfo person1 = new PersonInfo();

        person1.setNumKids(3);

        /* Your solution goes here  */
        System.out.println("Kids: " + person1.getNumKids());
        System.out.println("New baby, kids now: " + person1.getincNumKids());
        return;
```

Problem:

I'm having trouble incrementing and including the `incNumKids()` method, and print again

Comment: You need to call `incNumKids()` on your instance. Then you can call `getNumKids()` in the print statement and get the desired output. Furthermore, methods with return type `void` don't need a return statement (e.g. you can omit the `return;` line).

Answer (score 4):

Don't increment the number of kids within the println statement as it doesn't belong there -- it's not a statement that returns a String, but rather a method that changes the state of your PersonInfo object. Do it on its own on its own line, and then print the number of kids same as you did before, by calling `getNumKids()`. Also, don't call methods that simply don't exist, `getincNumKids()`??? There is no such method

```
public class CallPersonInfo {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
     PersonInfo person1 = new PersonInfo();

     person1.setNumKids(3);

     /* Your solution goes here  */
     System.out.println("Kids: " + person1.getNumKids());
     person1.incNumKids();
     System.out.println("Kids: " + person1.getNumKids());
     // return;  // no reason for this
```

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Heres what worked for me on the homework for my class

```
  /* Your solution goes here  */
  System.out.println("Kids: " + person1.getNumKids());
 person1.incNumKids();
 System.out.println("New baby, kids now: " + person1.getNumKids());
```

Its the correct solution for the homework I am working on right now. Hope this helps you. Heres for peeps needing help with hmwk. x3

Answer (score 1):

```
  person1.setNumKids(personsKid);
  int addOne;
  addOne = personsKid + 1;
  
  System.out.println("Kids: " + person1.getNumKids());
  person1.setNumKids(addOne);
  System.out.println("New baby, kids now: " + person1.getNumKids());
```